# Page layout with value of calendar control

Tags: 2010, calendar, page-layout, publishing-page

I've got a custom page layout in SP 2010 that will need an ASP.NET calendar control for editors to select a date. Then we want to show the selected date (or a default date if none selected) to the end users (not the calendar control).

The Article Date field won't work because we need editors to be able to select a date. How do you accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.datetimecontrol.aspx

Would this do?

A better explanation of how it works: 
http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/datetimecontrol-control/

Comment: Thanks, Natan. If someone doesn't have edit permissions to the page, I'd like just the date to display as a label, not as a control. Is this possible?

Comment: I think the answer is here: http://doseofdotnet.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/editmodepanel-behavior-changes-in-sharepoint-2010/ I want the content of the DateTimeControl to display for readers and for authors to display the control itself. Now to see how to implement this...